# Images for cycle tiles from web service

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

my app interacting with flickr and I want to add maybe 5 picture that I get from flickr json for my cycle tiles, how to do that? most of tutorial about making cycle tiles are using image from asset and none of them that teaching how to use from web service.

Answer (score 0):

You cant. Well Yes you can, but not directly. You should download it first.

I use this class from Brian Farnhill :

```
 public class TileManager
 {
      public const string StoragePath = "Shared/ShellContent";

      public static async Task SaveTileImage(Uri uri, string filename, string folder = StoragePath)
      {
           var client = new HttpClient();

           var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
           if (!isf.DirectoryExists(StoragePath))
                isf.CreateDirectory(StoragePath);

           var file = (folder == null ? filename : String.Format("{0}/{1}", folder, filename));
           if (isf.FileExists(file)) isf.DeleteFile(file);

           using (var stream = isf.OpenFile(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
           {
                var bytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(uri);
                var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes, false);
                await ms.CopyToAsync(stream); 
           }
      }

      public static void UpdateCycleTile(Uri smallBackgroundImage, string folder, string[] filesToShow, ShellTile currentTile)
      {
           var cycleTile = new CycleTileData
           {
                Title = "Stitch",
                SmallBackgroundImage = smallBackgroundImage,
                CycleImages = filesToShow.Select(str => String.Format("isostore:/{0}/{1}", folder, str).ToUri()).ToArray()
           };
           currentTile.Update(cycleTile);
      }
 }
```

Dont forget to add specific using and the package for HttpClient (nuget).

[source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_farnhill/archive/2014/01/05/using-the-cycletile-in-windows-phone-8-with-images-from-the-internet.aspx)